# Invalid Package Identity Error while submitting package to windows phone store

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps

Need some help in submitting my updated package after retargeting to windows phone 8.1.

After I load my solution in visual studio, I click retarget to windows phone 8.1.  Later AppxManifest file was created and now I made my changes to the application code and built XAP.  When I am submitting this build in windows phone store I am facing this below error:

```
Invalid package identity name: 2xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-bxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx (expected:)
Invalid package family name: 2xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-bxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx_m0ezkffm1mfsc (expected:)
```

Help me in submitting this XAP. What am I missing or What should I modify?

Comment: Which App you create Windows Phone 8.1(Silverlight / WinRT) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was confused with the new package identity implemented in windows phone 8.1. All I did was reserved a name in the store [I didnt do it for windows phone 8.0 app]. Then a package identity was created. I copied and put it in package.appxmanifest and rebuilt the application and that solved the errors.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It seems that when you converted from (I assume an already published) Windows 8 app to a Windows 8.1 app, some settings might not match with the previous app uploaded to the store.

Try double checking in your new Package.appxmanifest file that the PhoneProductID attribute of the mp:PhoneIdentity is mapped to the ProductID of your already published Windows 8 app. Same with PhonePublisherID and PublisherID.

You might find this guide useful:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn642081(v=vs.105).aspx